# NHibernate and indexed views (materialized views)

Tags: sql, nhibernate, orm, materialized-views, indexed-view

Recently I was busy implementing paging functionality with NHibernate and things went smoothly with simple entities, but I hit a performance problem with those ones where multiple joins are required to acquire the requested page. Besides that, implementation would be much simpler if the queries could be performed by convention without using all the twisted aliases and joins.

So I thought of so called **indexed views** or **materialized views**, which could solve both issues (or at least the performance one), but I couldn't find any guide or information on how to do it with NHibernate? The problem is more complex, because data are updated/inserted quite often for some entities, so eager updating would probably be necessary which could be a performance problem.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's been a while since this question, however ...

"Use [CQRS](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/)" would be a decent answer. Such problems can be elegantly avoided with using it.